# Adding text to GMSMapView without resizing

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need add some text strings to my GMSMapView, can do it like in solution of previous asked question here (get UIImage from UILabel then add GMSGroundOverlay with that image as icon to GMSMapView), but I need add text, which will not resize when user change zoom of the map.

[image]
[image]

You can see when user changes zoom of the map, my label changes font size too, but i need add label which will be looks same way as street names - without resizing when zoom. How to make it?

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution ?

Comment: Nope, solution was not found :(

Comment: How did you set "Job" text to GMSGroundOverlay center ? I have convert my lable to image and set as GMSGroundOverlay icon. But it will not set in center of GMSGroundOverlay.

Answer (score 1):

With your requirement, Why don't use `GMSMarker` instead of `GMSGroundOverlay` ?

This code works for me

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Adding label marker

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.text = @"Job";

label.opaque = NO;

label.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 14];
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

label.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
label.layer.masksToBounds = true;

label.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

GMSMarker *title = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:centerPosition];
title.icon = [self imageWithView:label];
title.map = mapView;
```

Comment: Hello. The question is tagged “Swift”, not Objective-C. Please post the Swift version so that OP can use your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Bùi Đức Khánh's answer above, Swift4

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

extension GMSMarker {
    convenience init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, text: String, backgroundColor: UIColor? = .white) {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
        label.isOpaque = false
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.backgroundColor = backgroundColor ?? .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        //label.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        //label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        //label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        //label.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        label.text = text
        self.init(position: position)
        icon = UIImage.imageFromView(label)
    }
}

 extension UIImage {
    class func imageFromView(_ view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        view.layer.render(in: context)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.1, 25.5),
                            text: "Lorem ipsum",
                            backgroundColor: .green)
marker.map = self.mapView
```